# Upgrade Error Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I have upgraded my store from Magento 2.2.7 to Magento 2.4.2 version and facing below error.

```
Warning: Class 'Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManagerSM2' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/autoload.php on line 15

Warning: Class 'Zend\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/autoload/formElementManagerPolyfill.php on line 16

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Stdlib\Glob' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Glob.php on line 14
```

Any help would be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

SanJay, we upgraded from Magento 2.4.1 to Magento 2.4.2 and We did not have your problem. Also the var/www/html/... folder structure does not appear in our configuration which leads me to think the folder structure has changed with recent upgrades.  Those may be old files that should be deleted.  Did you clear all cache and reindex after the upgrade?